# Having trouble removing an item from an array with splice

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**What I want to do**

I want to create a toggle function that allows a user to click on or off checkboxes by either adding them to an array (my state object), or if they're already there, removing them from the array.

**What I expect to happen**

with the following code, if the checkbox isn't in the selected array, it should be added. If it already exists, remove it:

```
   if (this.state.selected.indexOf(rowNumber) == -1) {

      let tempState = this.state.selected
      tempState.push(rowNumber)

      this.setState({
        selected: tempState
      })

    } else if (this.state.selected.indexOf(rowNumber) > -1 ){

      let tempIndex = this.state.selected.indexOf(rowNumber)
      let tempState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.selected))
      tempState = tempState.splice(tempIndex, 1)

      this.setState({
        selected: tempState
      })

    }
```

My state object is a simple array.

**What actually happens**

When splice activates, it removes the previously clicked element and not the one I'm currently clicking on.

I'd like to know why it's not just selecting/deselecting the currently clicked checkbox. Thanks!

edit: solved below!

Here's the link with the working example: https://repl.it/@yoursweater/MemorableJitteryAustraliancurlew

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: btw. `tempState.push(rowNumber)` is not ok, you are directly modifying state.

Comment: Yup Giorgi, thanks. Just noticed that right before you commented. I'm also doing a JSON.parse/stringify operation on it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.splice()` removes the elements in the array in place and returns the removed elements. Since you assign `tempState = tempState.splice(tempIndex, 1)`, `tempState` now contains the removed elements. You can just rewrite that line to be `tempState.splice(tempIndex, 1)` to fix it (no reassigning `tempState`).

Also instead of doing JSON parse/stringify, you can copy the array by using  `a = b.slice()`

Comment: Ahhhh not sure how I missed that! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Might I just suggest a different approach? Arrays is JavaScript can handle setting non-consecutive indices, so you can start with an empty array like this:

```
const state = [];
```

...and then do something like this:

```
state[3] = true;
```

...and then you'll have an array that looks like this:

```
[undefined, undefined, undefined, true];
```

You can also then access an out-of-bounds index, and it's simply treated as undefined as well.

```
if (state[5]) {
  console.log('You won\'t see this.');
}
else {
  console.log('You will see this.');
}
```

Because of the way JavaScript arrays work, you can store and toggle your button states simply by doing:

```
state[rowNumber] = !state[rowNumber];
```